# in reactjs, is it possible to create a tab control that does not reset the state of the content?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

here is my react hooks code:

```
function Panel({children,title}){
    var [count,set_count]=React.useState(0)
    React.useEffect(_=>{
        console.log(title,'mount')
        return _x=>console.log(title,'unmount')
    })
    function onClick(){
        set_count(count+10)
    }
    return <>{count}<button  {...{onClick}}>up</button><div>{children}</div></>
} 
function Tabs({children}){
    var [selected,set_selected]=React.useState(children[0].key)
    var tabs= children.map(x=>{
        function onClick(){
            set_selected(x.key)
        }
        var className=(selected==x.key)?'tab selected':'tab'
        return <div {...{className,onClick,key:x.key}}>{x.props.title||x.key}</div>
    })
    var panel=children.find(x=>x.key==selected)
    return <><div>{tabs}</div>{panel}</>
}
function TabsPage(){
    return <Tabs>
        <Panel key='the_tab1' title='The tab1 title'> tab1<b>rrr</b></Panel>
        <Panel key='the_tab2' title='The tab2 title'> tab2</Panel>
        </Tabs>
}
```

The goal is to use react hooks to create a simple tab control with arbitrary content (called Panels). The code works, except that the panel components mount/unmount every time the user change the active tab. As result the panels state reset.

my question: how to make the state not reset when changing tabs? is it at all possible without using global state store such as redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state resets on tab changes because you re-render panel variable in Tabs component each time you change the selected tab. To keep the state, you have 2 options:

- Instead of redux, keep the state in TabsPage component, so it won't be lost when a panel is unmounted.
- Render all the tabs at all the time, but only display the selected one (using CSS properties like display or visibility). This way, components will not be unmounted so you can keep the state.

Also, even though it's not related to your question, I want to note that with the `useEffect` code you use in Panel component, you don't track the mount/unmount state. Instead, it is triggered at each render. If you want your effect to be called at mount and unmount once, you need add a dependency array to your effect. Check [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: yes, that makes sense and consistent with what i read elsewhere. i wish react had someway to configure components not reset state on mount/dismount

Answer (score 1):

This is quite misconception that `useEffect` in react hook has a mount effect and clean up in the `useEffect` has an unmount effect (Even I had this thinking when I was learning hooks).

In short, each render has its own state, props and effects. And the clean up function inside the clean up called before the effect takes place again. Thats when the dependency of each effect comes into picture which govern when the `useEffect` takes place. Currently the `useEffect` you have executes on every render as it has no dependency.

I would highly recommend reading this blog [post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) in order to understand how `useEffect` behaves.

Coming to the solution to this, it would be to implement the active panel `TabsPage` and send the selectedKey to the `Panel`. If the key is same, you can toggle showing the content.

So the component will look something similar to this

```
function TabsPage() {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = React.useState(the_tab1);
  const handlePanelClick = useCallback((id) => {
    setSelectedKey(id);
  }, []);
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Panel
        key="the_tab1"
        title="The tab1 title"
        selectedKey={selectedKey}
        onClick={handlePanelClick}
      >
        tab1<b>rrr</b>
      </Panel>
      <Panel
        key="the_tab2"
        title="The tab2 title"
        selectedKey={selectedKey}
        onClick={handlePanelClick}
      >
        tab2
      </Panel>
    </Tabs>
  );
}

function Panel({ key, children, handlePanelClick, selectedKey }) {
  return (
    <>
      {/** to show hide the panel */}
      <button onClick={() => handlePanelClick(key)}>+</button>
      {key === selectedKey && <div>{children}</div>}
    </>
  );
}
```